Complex numbers using hence result
Using $\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)\left(1+\cos\theta-i\sin\theta\right)=1+\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$
Find $\left(1+cis\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)^{6}+\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)^{6}$
I'm not sure whether to use the LHS or RHS to compute the first expression in the pair of sixth powers? Could someone offer some guidance?

Are you sure it's not $$\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)^6$$?

@ultralegend5385 yes that is right

Personally, I don't see any quick/easy way of using the first line in the posted question to simplify the second line.  So, depending on the original poster's response to the comment/question of ultralegend, I would simply consult the 6th row of Pascal's Triangle and simply multiply everything out.  Then, once a final answer is reached, I would make one last effort to try to find some connection between the final answer and the first line of the posted question.  So, even if no connection is solved, the problem is still conquered.

it might help to notice the second term in the sum is $(1+cis(-\pi/6))^6$

@Nic full solution comon, provide for the poor

Write $\zeta:=\exp{\frac{2\pi i}{12}}$.
The given identity is $\zeta(1+\zeta^{-1})=1+\zeta$.
Now
$$
\begin{align}
&(1+\zeta)^6+(1+\zeta^{-1})^6\\
&=\zeta^6(1+\zeta^{-1})^6+(1+\zeta^{-1})^6\\
&=(\zeta^6+1)(1+\zeta^{-1})^6\\
&=0(1+\zeta^{-1})^6\\
&=0.
\end{align}
$$

I'll just add a few identities that OP might not know: $ \exp\frac{2\pi i}{12} = cis(2\pi/12) = cis(\pi/6) $ so $\zeta = cis(\pi/6)$. Also $cis\theta_1 * cis\theta_2 = cis(\theta_1+\theta_2)$. This gives us that $\zeta^6 = cis(6*\pi/6) = cis(\pi) = -1$. This is also why $cis(-\pi/6) = cis(\pi/6)^{-1}$.
